# Could a large panel of LEDs be used for station keeping in earth orbit?

Tags: photons, orbital-motion, satellites, light-emitting-diodes

Hall effect and other ion thrusters require propellant to operate and thus have a limited usable lifespan in orbit.

In typical operational use, the force they produce is in the 25mN - 250mN range. It's not much, but it is enough to do station keeping for satellites.

We know photons have momentum and we also know that LEDs can produce photons from electricity. No propellant needed, just electricity.

I attempted to do some calculations, but my high school physics from a couple of decades ago has failed me. Here are some of the assumptions I was working with:

- The smallest wavelength for commercially available LEDs is about
  250nm.
- The momentum of a photon at 250nm is ~$2.65×10^{-27}$ N•s
- Ion thrusters typically have a power range of 1-7kW, so assume that is the power available to an LED panel.

My questions are:

1. How large/powerful would an LED panel need to be replace a 100mN ion
   thruster on a satellite?
2. If even doable, would this give the satellite an effectively
   unlimited lifespan, assuming no other parts failed?
3. Are there better/more efficient light sources that would make this
   feasible? A photon's a photon's a photon, so I suspect not.

Comment: In other words a photonic rocket/engine? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_rocket

Comment: Thanks for that link, I hadn't seen it before. It confirms the answer provided below by Dan.

Comment: It's actually the first time I've heard of the device but it doesn't surprise me that it exists as a concept considering solar sails are also a considered short range propulsion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between energy and momentum for electromagnetic radiation is $$E = pc$$ where $E$ is the energy, $p$ the momentum, and $c$ is the speed of light.

So the relation between force $F$ provided by a beam of light with power $W$ is $$W= Fc.$$ ​
You chose a force of 100 mN. I'm supposing that means micro Newtons, or $$100 \times 10^{-6}  \text{ Newtons} = 10^{-4} \text{ Newtons.} $$

So the power you require is $$ W = 10^{-4} \text{ Newtons} \times c = 3 \times 10^{4} \text{ Watts.}$$
Note that this is the power that must be in the light, not just the power provided to the LEDs. If they were 33% efficient, you would need three times that in electrical power. Also note, if mN meant milli-Newton rather than micro-Newton, you would need 1000 times more.

Comment: Yes, I interpreted the mN unit mentioned in the Ion Thruster wikipedia page as being the SI prefix milli.

Triatticus above linked me to the [Photonic Nuclear Rocket](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_photonic_rocket) page, which states:

`The power per thrust required for a perfectly collimated output beam is 300 MW/N`

which lines up exactly with your calculations!